# Parametrized twig date

Tags: twig

I need how to check if a custom date is inside a range.

The problem is that the API returns a calendar but year and month are sent separately and I can't create a date with `twig`.

This part of the code seems to return my variables as expected

```
<script>console.log("Year"+{{CurrYear| json_encode()| raw}});</script>
<script>console.log("Month: "+{{CurrMonth| json_encode()| raw}});</script>
```

while I can retrieve the day within the loop

```
<script>console.log("Day: "+{{key| json_encode()| raw}});</script>
```

I'm trying to create a data item so I can use the native comparisons. I know I can split the other date and compare it one by one, but I'm trying to avoid this

```
<script>console.log({{ annoForm."-".mesForm."-".key |date('Y-m-d')}}) ;</script>
```

So I can use it afterwards like

```
{% set auxDate = annoForm."-".mesForm."-".key |date('Y-m-d') %}
```

BUT, I can't seem to construct a valid date here so I could use it in:

```
{% datestart < auxDate  and dateend > auxDate  %}
  {# condition met #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'd strongly advice to do this stuff in your controller, but if you wanted to compare dates inside `twig` u'd better be off with using the unix timestamp `{{ my_date|date('U') }}`

Comment: I was looking for some "clear way" altering only one file. Since I have to make changes to the template and the information was already passed I expected a native constructor to exist.  I also thought to take "now" , substract day, year and month and add my variables but that seems like a total botch job to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem here was concatenating correctly the string when instantiating date():

```
{% set auxDate = ("#{annoForm}-#{mesForm}-#{key} " | date('Y-m-d') ) %}
```

I want to add a couple of issues i found while working on this.
First the importance of using date('Y-m-d') instead of "date()" because it will consider July before June (due alphabetic order).

Take nulls or open fields into account (in my case datestart is mandatory)

```
{% if  datestart < auxDate and ( dateend is null or dateend > auxDate ) %}
```

Hope it helps!